# How to generate self-signed cert using subjectAltName with dirName using OpenSSL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl

I am attempting to generate a self-signed cert with a SubjectAltName of type DirName.  Other types of  SubjectAltName like DNS work just fine, but DirName will not work.  The code to reproduce fairly simple (python 3.8.5)

```
import string
from OpenSSL import crypto

def _create_csr():
    key = crypto.PKey()
    key.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 2048)
    csr = crypto.X509Req()
    csr.set_pubkey(key)

    works = "DNS:abc.xyz"
    fails = "dirName:MyGeneratedCert"
    csr.add_extensions([crypto.X509Extension(b"subjectAltName", False, fails.encode("ascii"))])
    csr.sign(key, "sha256")

if __name__=="__main__": 
    _create_csr()
```

The exception I am receiving is as the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/createcert.py", line 16, in <module>
    _create_csr()
  File "tests/createcert.py", line 12, in _create_csr
    csr.add_extensions([crypto.X509Extension(b"subjectAltName", False, fails.encode("ascii"))])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 779, in __init__
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('X509 V3 routines', 'X509V3_get_section', 'operation not defined'), ('X509 V3 routines', 'do_dirname', 'section not found'), ('X509 V3 routines', 'a2i_GENERAL_NAME', 'dirname error'), ('X509 V3 routines', 'X509V3_EXT_nconf', 'error in extension')]
```

The call is making it into OpenSSL's do_dirname function (stack trace).  I assume that the value is not being passed in in correct way, but I cannot understand how to pass it as desired.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have found the solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, via python, because dirName references a value in the configuration database, but pyOpenSSL does not provide an interface to create a configuration database.

Background: dirName references a section in the database, which could be a config file. Reference the x509v3_config tool, for example (https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/doc/man5/x509v3_config.pod) where you may use a config file:

```
  [extensions]
  subjectAltName = dirName:dir_sect

  [dir_sect]
  C = UK
  O = My Org
  OU = My Unit
  CN = My Name
```

Note how `dirName` simply refers to a different section in the configuration database.

But pyopenssl does not have a provision for creating such a database, so your dirName reference won't be found -- hence your error.

Note this is a known limitation. The Python code itself includes mention of lack of configuration database: See comment in code: https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/blob/master/src/OpenSSL/crypto.py, line approx 754:

```
# We have no configuration database - but perhaps we should (some
# extensions may require it).
```